# TestComplete:How to run Run dialog box through C# scripting in Testcomplete?

Tags: testcomplete

In one of my tests, i need to open Run Dialog Box and open an application.
How can i open 'Run' in the very first step using C# script in Testcomplete.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not simply launch the app using TestedApps, or Sys.OleObject("WScript.Shell").[Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx)(*path*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helen is right: the best way is to just use the [Tested Applications](http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/31408/) feature. However, if you must use the Run dialog for some reason, you can open it using this code of line:

```
Sys.Keys("[Hold][Win]r[Release]");
```

Comment: @user2993178: If an answer helped you, consider upvoting it and/or marking the answer as accepted by clicking the check mark. Accepting an answer marks the problem as solved and gives both you and answerer some reputation points.